# "SecurityError: This operation is insecure" when calling domtoimage.toPng() in OpenLayers example

Tags: javascript, django, dom, openlayers

I am currently working on adding functionality to convert an OpenLayers Map into a png file (The example is [here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-map.html)). However, when calling `domtoimage.toPng()` in the below code, Firefox (Ubuntu version 68.0.2) gives me the error `SecurityError: This operation is insecure`. I have checked all around and no one else seems to be having this problem with the dom-to-image library, and so I am stuck on how to fix this error. My JavaScript code for the Map is very similar to the code given in the example and is given here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var extent = [0, 0, 3000, 4213];
var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
    code: 'my-image',
    units: 'pixels',
    extent: extent,
});
var map = new ol.Map({
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
        new ol.control.FullScreen()
    ]),
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Image({
            source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
                attributions: 'My Image Attributions',
                url: "{{record | img_url}}", // Django stuff defined earlier
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: extent
            })
        })
    ],
    target: 'map', 
    view: new ol.View({ 
        projection: projection,
        center: ol.extent.getCenter(extent),
        zoom: 2, 
        maxZoom: 8
    })
});

map.addOverlay(new ol.Overlay({
    position: [0, 0],
    element: document.getElementById('null')
}));


// export options for dom-to-image.
var exportOptions = {
    filter: function(element) {
        return element.className ? element.className.indexOf('ol-control') === -1 : true;
    }
};

document.getElementById('export-png').addEventListener('click', function() {
    map.once('rendercomplete', function() {
        domtoimage.toPng(map.getTargetElement(), exportOptions)
            .then(function(dataURL) {
                var link = document.getElementById('image-download');
                link.href = dataURL;
                link.click();
            });
    });
    map.renderSync();
});
```

The HTML is effectively the same as in the example and so I believe the problem lies somewhere in here. Perhaps it is something with using a StaticImage in the Map? Or maybe going through the Django framework tampers with it in some unknown way? I am not entirely sure, and any diagnosis/help with fixing this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there should be something like:

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
    name: 'name',
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        ...
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous' // <-- Add this to the json.
    })
})
```

> **Read more:**
>
> https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.source.ImageWMS.html
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thank you.